# Can I install Ubuntu on major OEM systems?

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

I want to buy a laptop and install Ubuntu on it. Most laptops these days are Windows 10 based, which require a UEFI secure boot, but don't require it to be unlocked.

So I can imagine that most OEMs don't turn it off.

Would I be able to install Ubuntu on a Dell/HP/Lenova computer and (at least) have it boot?

Comment: Just purchase a system with Linux pre-installed. http://www.fit-pc.com/web/products/ or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : **YES** !

Even if you cannot disable Secure Boot (in most of all cases you can),
you can install Ubuntu ... because it comes with a signed boot loader.